# Opening New Web Page From HTML Using Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to have a webpage, take some user search input and then pass that input to a new page using the Play Framework. But, I'm having some problems doing that. I feel like this is probably rather straightforward, but I just can't quite get it working.

My Routes:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
GET     /:search                    controllers.Application.getSearchResult(search)
GET     /push-notifications         controllers.Application.socket
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public/app", file: Asset)
```

Controller:

```
  def index = Action { request =>
    Ok(views.html.index.render)
  }

  def getSearchResult(search: String) = Action { request =>
    val databaseSupport = new InteractWithDatabase(comm, db)
    val put = Future {
      while (true) {
        val data = databaseSupport.getFromDatabase(search)
        if (data.nonEmpty) {
          comm.communicator ! data.head
        }
      }
    }
    Logger.info("Gotcha")
    Ok(views.html.singleElement.render)
  }
```

index.scala.html:

```
@()

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <h3>A demonstration of how to access a Search field</h3>

            <input type="search" id="search" value="mySearch" placeholder="Search for something...">
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

        <p>Click the button to get the placeholder text of the search field.</p>

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var input = document.getElementById("search").value.toString();
                window.location = @routes.Application.getSearchResult(input);
            }
        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

I feel like I'm making some big conceptual error here. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of problems could be your `/:search` route. It should come last, because it will match last 2 routes also.. More specific routes come first.

Comment: Could you also tell what exactly not working?
Also what is visible right on the surface is that you declare a value `val put = Future{...}` and actually never use it. So why are you declaring it?
Also you feed into that future what seems for me to be an endless loop and the reason of doing this is also not clear for me.
Try to declare in your code the precise type of this Future[A], so you know for yourself what exactly you suppose to be returned from it and try to do something with that value via future's `map` method for example.

Comment: Nothing happens. IntelliJ seems to not even know what `input` is as it says `cannot resolve symbol input`. It won't redirect to anything, and just stays put. 
On the note about the `val put = Future{...}`, that is a thread on which I continue to query a database and pass whatever I get through a web socket to the singleElement page. By the nature of `Future` it is called automatically and should return nothing as all the work is being done right there. For now it's an infinite loop, but that will change soon.

Comment: I haven't read the full question because I'm just searching for answers on a topic myself but I've very quickly noticed that in your `Routes` file you have: `controllers.Application.getSearchResult(search)` - I've always declared the type of the parameter there, i.e. `controllers.Application.getSearchResult(search: String)`